# What would be Python/pandas equivalent of this R code for rearranging columns of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
data<-data[c(8,1:7)]
```

Basically, move the last column to the first position. How would I do this in Python by using only column indices, preferably in a single line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `.iloc[]`:

```
data = data.iloc[:, [7] + list(range(7))]
```

Or: `data = data[[7] + list(range(7))]`

---

Just keep in mind that

- in python index is zero based while R is one based;
- R uses vector for indexing while python uses list.

Answer (score 8):

use `numpy.r_`
This was intended to allow `R` like syntax for array slicing.  Hence the `r_`

Assuming your dataframe is named `df`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = df.iloc[:, np.r_[8, 1:7]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data = data[[7,0,1,2,3,4,5,6]]
```

in case you have a lot of columns..

```
data = data[list(df.columns.tolist()[-1]) + df.columns.tolist()[:-1]]
```

Comment: I had a similar thought.  JMO, but I think in this case it's actually better to do in 2 lines in this case:  (1) `col = df.columns.tolist()`  (2)
`df = df[ col[-1:] + col[:-1] ]`