# Slicing multiple column ranges from a dataframe using iloc

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a df with 32 columns

```
df.shape
(568285, 32)
```

I am trying to rearrange the columns in a specific way, and drop the first column using iloc

```
 df = df.iloc[:,[31,[1:23],24,25,26,28,27,29,30]]
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/a/41540037/2137255

Comment: @JohnGalt need to improve search skills, apologies

Comment: Give it time, we all were there. :)

Comment: @novicebioinforesearcher Also, it is important to note, dupes aren't bad.  Sometimes we search differently.  Or you just aren't aware of what to search for.  It shouldn't be reflective of negative judgement on you or your question.  In fact, lot's of rep was earned from this question and answer.  All marking  dupes accomplishes is redirecting search results to the dupe targets.  So, in fact, you've helped by including additional search terms that will re-route to the other answer (-:

Comment: Ahh, I see makes sense on dupes concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a custom solution using explicit indexing:

*Side note, `np.r_` wasn't working for me, which is why I built this solution.*

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Make a sample df of 1_000 rows & 100 cols
data = np.zeros(shape=(1_000,100))
df = pd.DataFrame(data)


# Create a custom function for indexing
def all_nums_in_range(*tuple_pairs, len_df):
    """
    Input pairs of tuples for index slicing

    Include `len_df` to ensure length of array matches indexed df
    """

    # Create an array with values to use as an index
    num_range = np.zeros(shape=(len_df,), dtype=bool)

    # Update
    for (start, end) in tuple_pairs:
        num_range[start:end] = True

    return num_range


# Now apply
num_range = all_nums_in_range((0,50), (75, 80), len_df=100)
df.iloc[:, num_range]
```

Comment: Old question, but I had this same question, and `np.r_` wasn't originally working for me either. By any chance were you slicing with the implicit semicolon syntax like `np.r_[5, :2]` to mean `[5, 0, 1]` for example? In case that was the reason why it wasn't working for you, explicitly using `np.r_[5, 0:2]` gave the intended result for me.


Just posting this for anyone who wanted to use `np.r_` instead.

Answer (score 34):

You could use the `np.r_` indexer.

> ```
> class RClass(AxisConcatenator)
>  |  Translates slice objects to concatenation along the first axis.
>  |  
>  |  This is a simple way to build up arrays quickly. There are two use cases.
> ```

---

```
df = df.iloc[:, np.r_[31, 1:23, 24, 25, 26, 28, 27, 29, 30]]
```

---

```
df

     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9   ...     40  \
A  33.0  44.0  68.0  31.0   NaN  87.0  66.0   NaN  72.0  33.0  ...   71.0   
B   NaN   NaN  77.0  98.0   NaN  48.0  91.0  43.0   NaN  89.0  ...   38.0   
C  45.0  55.0   NaN  72.0  61.0  87.0   NaN  99.0  96.0  75.0  ...   83.0   
D   NaN   NaN   NaN  58.0   NaN  97.0  64.0  49.0  52.0  45.0  ...   63.0   

     41    42    43    44    45    46    47    48    49  
A   NaN  87.0  31.0  50.0  48.0  73.0   NaN   NaN  81.0  
B  79.0  47.0  51.0  99.0  59.0   NaN  72.0  48.0   NaN  
C  93.0   NaN  95.0  97.0  52.0  99.0  71.0  53.0  69.0  
D   NaN  41.0   NaN   NaN  55.0  90.0   NaN   NaN  92.0

out = df.iloc[:, np.r_[31, 1:23, 24, 25, 26, 28, 27, 29, 30]]
out 
     31    1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9   ...     20  \
A  99.0  44.0  68.0  31.0   NaN  87.0  66.0   NaN  72.0  33.0  ...   66.0   
B  42.0   NaN  77.0  98.0   NaN  48.0  91.0  43.0   NaN  89.0  ...    NaN   
C  77.0  55.0   NaN  72.0  61.0  87.0   NaN  99.0  96.0  75.0  ...   76.0   
D  95.0   NaN   NaN  58.0   NaN  97.0  64.0  49.0  52.0  45.0  ...   71.0   

     21    22    24    25    26    28    27    29    30  
A   NaN  40.0  66.0  87.0  97.0  68.0   NaN  68.0   NaN  
B  95.0   NaN  47.0  79.0  47.0   NaN  83.0  81.0  57.0  
C   NaN  75.0  46.0  84.0   NaN  50.0  41.0  38.0  52.0  
D   NaN  74.0  41.0  55.0  60.0   NaN   NaN  84.0   NaN
```