# python: data was added an extra column after sampled to a small dataset

Tags: python, sample

This is odd to me:

I have a 5 columns csv dataset with the first couple rows as below:

```
1,2268318,2520377,pv,1511544070
1,2333346,2520771,pv,1511561733
1,2576651,149192,pv,1511572885
1,3830808,4181361,pv,1511593493
1,4365585,2520377,pv,1511596146
1,4606018,2735466,pv,1511616481
```

Code to sample the data:

```
df = pd.read_csv(
        filename,
        header=0
        )
ddf = df.sample(n=100150)
ddf.to_csv(samplename, sep=',')
```

Generated sampling file is like:

```
1,2268318,2520377,pv,1511544070
50533941,564438,1311198,2806049,pv,1511700754
53243335,689136,111697,154040,pv,1512264559
68168213,452960,119903,1151115,pv,1511711183
18695132,942795,2288684,1526856,pv,1511594854
```

You can see for some odd reason the sampling data contains 6 columns except the first row (first row is correct).

What's wrong with the code? How do I get a randomly generated sample (with adjustable ratio)?

I am using python 3.6 in spyder/pycharm.

Thank you.

Comment: I suggest you read the docs for [`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and [`to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html). There you'll note that `header=0` for `read_csv` is the default and means the first row is treated as a header. Most likely you want `header=None`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is your first data row is set to columns names.

So need change `header=0` to `header=None` for default `RangeIndex` columns names.

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""1,2268318,2520377,pv,1511544070
1,2333346,2520771,pv,1511561733
1,2576651,149192,pv,1511572885
1,3830808,4181361,pv,1511593493
1,4365585,2520377,pv,1511596146
1,4606018,2735466,pv,1511616481"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), header=None)

print (df)
   0        1        2   3           4
0  1  2268318  2520377  pv  1511544070
1  1  2333346  2520771  pv  1511561733
2  1  2576651   149192  pv  1511572885
3  1  3830808  4181361  pv  1511593493
4  1  4365585  2520377  pv  1511596146
5  1  4606018  2735466  pv  1511616481
```

Extra first column is called index, if need remove it if write `DataFrame` to `csv` use parameter `index=False` and for remove columns names `header=None`:

```
df.to_csv(file, index=False, header=None)

1,2268318,2520377,pv,1511544070
1,2333346,2520771,pv,1511561733
1,2576651,149192,pv,1511572885
1,3830808,4181361,pv,1511593493
1,4365585,2520377,pv,1511596146
1,4606018,2735466,pv,1511616481
```

EDIT:

I suggest create custom columns names for easier working with data by parameter `names` (`header=None` is not necessary) and for remove some column use [`drop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""1,2268318,2520377,pv,1511544070
1,2333346,2520771,pv,1511561733
1,2576651,149192,pv,1511572885
1,3830808,4181361,pv,1511593493
1,4365585,2520377,pv,1511596146
1,4606018,2735466,pv,1511616481"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), names=['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5'])
print (df)
   col1     col2     col3 col4        col5
0     1  2268318  2520377   pv  1511544070
1     1  2333346  2520771   pv  1511561733
2     1  2576651   149192   pv  1511572885
3     1  3830808  4181361   pv  1511593493
4     1  4365585  2520377   pv  1511596146
5     1  4606018  2735466   pv  1511616481

df1 = df.drop('col4', axis=1)
print (df1)
   col1     col2     col3        col5
0     1  2268318  2520377  1511544070
1     1  2333346  2520771  1511561733
2     1  2576651   149192  1511572885
3     1  3830808  4181361  1511593493
4     1  4365585  2520377  1511596146
5     1  4606018  2735466  1511616481
```

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. Not correct though, the new dataset becomes:,0,1,2,3,4
2537115,197638,1046007,4756105,pv,1511606930
One extra column is added somehow.

Comment: It extra column is called index, if need remove it in write to csv use `df.to_csv(file, index=False, header=None)`

Comment: Thanks.    df = pd.read_csv(filename,index=False,header=None)
TypeError: parser_f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index'

Comment: @Choix - In read_csv is no parameter `index`, because each DataFrame has index, default RangeIndex. Removing is possible if write to csv only.

Comment: Thank you. In the above dataframe, how do I exclude the result column (i.e. showing pv) and keep the rest?

Comment: I found the way to slice multiple columns [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45985877/slicing-multiple-column-ranges-from-a-dataframe-using-iloc}

Comment: @Choix - Edited answer, I suggest use `drop`

Comment: Thank you very much @jezrael.